# Named vs unnamed prepared statement placeholder speed differencies?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, placeholder

Is there any speed differences when I use PDO's prepared statement with named placeholders (`:param`), compared to the prepared statement with unnamed placehoders (`?`)?

I am writing script which will do millions of inserts+updates, so any speed improvement would be welcome.

Comment: compared to the appropriate indexes and hardware setup? negligible.

Comment: What do your metrics tell you? As long as you haven't run any metrics, please don't ask. We can't test on your system/configuration.

Comment: @hakre: that does not make it "not a real question". It is very clear what is being asked, even if it's misguided.

Answer (score 2):

Utterly, utterly insignificant. There may be a difference in theory, but it will be a million times less than actually executing even a single DB statement.

Answer (score 0):

Oh noooooo.
There shouldn't be such a question at all.

Ask for the speed difference only if you have **the certain bottleneck.**
But you can be sure there is **no** bottleneck connected to such a trifle operation like query preparation.

There can be speed improvement for the millions of inserts of course.
But one have to ask it with some sense, not as just a wild guess, taking random part of syntax.

Millions of inserts is a serious operation and there is always a way to improve the speed.
But why don't you ask this very question (providing necessary details an all these millions), instead of asking such an irrelevant one?